# How change the value of variable in api url dynamically using HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api, curl

I am getting the value of $mc_out with the below code:

```
    <input type="text" id="input"><?php $mc_out = '<span style="display:none;">oninput:</span> <span 
    id="result"></span>' ;?>

   <script>
  input.oninput = function() {
   result.innerHTML = input.value;
   };
  </script>
```

Now i am using this variable $mc_out in my api to get value dynamically. $mc_out value is changing everytime i change the value in form above but its not working in the below api without refresh. And once the page refreshed then $mc_out will become empty unless i enter the value again in the form.

```
                $curl = curl_init();

                curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                  CURLOPT_URL => "http://test-api-dev.testurl.org/in_school/$mc_out",
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "Authorization: Bearer $final_token"
                  ),
                ));

                $response = curl_exec($curl);
                $data = json_decode($response, true);
                print_r($data);
```

please help me with this problem.

Comment: Is there more going on with your HTML that you haven't shown because from what I can see the PHP variable $mc_out contains a string of HTML, not a value, and that HTML is not output to the DOM so span#result wouldn't exist in the DOM. Also the javascript variables input and result are not declared so how have they been set?

Comment: Thank you for your response Mark. Please guide me through this and help in getting this implemented. Html is only this. my main concern is to get the value of text box filled by user and pass it in the api to show the result.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot spend too much time right now. I can give you some pointers though. The curl request must be a separate PHP file from the HTML. It should obtain the value from a $_GET request variable. That variable should be sent to the PHP script via AJAX. The HTML and JavaScript (event handler and AJAX) should be in a separate html file. Please see the tutorial on W3Schools on AJAX https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp to get started. If you are still stuck next week then I should be able to help then.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your response. But in my case i want all the things to happen on same page. As per the value entered in text box, will help to execute the api as this value will be added to the api url. and then value getting from api needs to be shown on the same page.

Comment: What happens on the html side cannot possibly affect the php side. PHP is stateless so you have to either submit the form each time to pass in the new value or use ajax like I have suggested.

Comment: yes agreed. I will have to do it with ajax only. But not getting any proper solution/example which can help me in implementation process.